# Detect changes made by installer Folder Recursively c:\ and Registry Regedit, Windows 7

Tags: recursion, windows-7, registry, virtual-machine

I'm using a virtual machine with Windows 7.

I want to see what changes does an installer on Directories and Folder and Registry (Regedit).

1. List all hidden Folders/Files recursively on Windows 7 Sharing C:\ from External Host.

Like on Linux/Unix I can do: `ls -AlR / > AllFiles.txt`

But I want to do from Windows.

Detect changes in the Registry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RegShot](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/regshot_portable) to take before and after snapshots of the Windows registry and file system, it gives you a report with all the changes.

[image]